# React Material-ui takes too long every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

This is my first experience with React `Material-ui`. In my react app, whenever I use `yarn start`, it takes too long (at least `25 seconds` on a processor `i5 8400 + 16 GB RAM`) to compile then start the react app.

At first, I thought it could be due to `eslint`, but after disabling it, there was no tangible improvement. Next, I thought it might be about `material-ui`. When I tried removing it completely, it went back to a normal react-app with a fast start.

Is it always this long or can I do something to ensure it isn't always as long?

Comment: It takes quite a lot of time for me too, why do you need to boot the app quicker than that? With hot reload or fast refresh enabled, you can have the app running and see the changes to the code in real time so you only have to start the app once anyways. Sounds like you for some reason need to restart the app all the time? (I assume we are talking about dev mode here and not production)

Comment: Despite this being a really time-consuming and annoying process in CI/CD, I cannot accept this and believe it should be solved instead of ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Tree shaking", which will HIGHLY reduce the bundle size of material UI (which I believe is the issue here), and will ultimately load your app faster. To learn what Tree Shaking is, and how you can use it, material UI provides [an article on how to reduce bundle size](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/).

Comment: I don't think so, Because tree shake is for compiling the project for production mode, But the problem here is about develop time which I've said using `yarn start`

Comment: If you read the website, it specifically says that it speeds up development compile time

Comment: I'll try it, and tell you what happend.